# Count observations by day of year using lubridate in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am trying to count the number of observations by the day of the year. Here are six observations:

```
six_obs <- data.frame(Date = c("2015-09-06 00:00:12 UTC", "2015-09-06 00:01:47 UTC", "2015-09-06 00:03:30 UTC", "2015-10-06 00:03:31 UTC", "2015-10-06 00:03:36 UTC", "2015-10-06 00:06:18 UTC"), Count = c(6, 4, 5, 4, 5, 7), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

In order to group them by day of the year, I can do something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

six_obs %>%
    mutate(Date = ymd_hms(Date),
           day_of_year = yday(Date)) %>%
    group_by(day_of_year) %>%
    summarize(number_of_obs = n())
```

This works fine, but if I have very many dates over multiple years, then this will not straightforwardly work, because the `lubridate` function `yday` returns an integer between `1` and `365`.

Is there a way to group by the day of the year? One solution is to use the `lubridate` functions `yday` and `year` and then to `paste` `yday` and `year` together, but it seems like there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, grouped by date (day, month, year) is what I mean. That does work - but what if there are observations every day for multiple years? The year is not accounted for, and so dates with the same day (i.e., Jan 10 = yday 10) are grouped together

Comment: Got it, thanks. One other thing. I notice that we have the `Count` column, but in the `dplyr` example you didn't use it. Do you just want the count of the number of times that a date appears, or did you want the sum of `Count` by date?

Comment: I apologize `Hack-R`, that `Count` variable was basically a distractor, since I thought I needed more than one variable to use a `data.frame` with `dplyr`.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::count` is equivalent to `group_by(...) %>% summarise(n = n())`, so you really only need

```
six_obs %>% count(day_of_year = date(Date))

## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##   day_of_year     n
##        <date> <int>
## 1  2015-09-06     3
## 2  2015-10-06     3
```

where `lubridate::date` simply converts (or parses, if the `Date` column is character) to Date class, mostly equivalent to `as.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `date` function or use `round_date(Date, units = "day")`. <s>Alternatively you can just cast it to Date to get rid of the timestamp: `as.Date(Date)`</s>(EDIT: Not recommended) . A third option is to use the `truncated` argument for the `ymd_hms` function.

Comment: Just be careful with `as.Date(posixctdatetime)` as you can get unexpected results if you are dealing with non-UTC datetimes - `as.Date(as.POSIXct("2000/01/01",tz="Australia/Brisbane"))` for example.

Comment: You're right. Instead, the `date` function from lubridate should be probably be used.

Comment: I will add this to my answer as well. Good call.

Comment: Edited my answer above to reflect @thelatemail's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a sequence of dates and then use the cut command to group and summarize the results.  No need to use lubridate.
See this example using created data:

```
#generate sample data
Date<-seq(from= as.POSIXct("2016-06-01"), by="1 min", length.out = 9000)
value<-rnorm(9000, 50)
df<-data.frame(Date, value)


#group the results by 1 day intervals
library(dplyr)
out<-summarize(group_by(df, cut(df$Date, breaks="1 day") ), n())
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from the comments is that you'd like to summarize the data by date.

If you want to sum the counts in `Count` by date then we can do so like this:

```
aggregate(six_obs$Count, by=list(as.Date(six_obs$Date)),sum)
```

> ```
>      Group.1  x
> 1 2015-09-06 15
> 2 2015-10-06 16
> ```

or using `date()` from `lubridate`:

```
aggregate(six_obs$Count, by=list(date(as.character(six_obs$Date))),sum)
```

If you only want to sum up the count of the occurrence of the date in the `Date` field, ignoring `Count`, then just do:

```
table(as.Date(six_obs$Date))
```

> ```
> 2015-09-06 2015-10-06 
>          3          3
> ```

or

```
table(date(six_obs$Date))
```